# How to estimate the following integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, inequality

I would like to estimate the integral $I_{s,t}$ by a constant $C$ independent of $s, t \in \mathbb S^1$:

$$I_{s,t}=\int_{|r-s|\geq 2|t-s|} \frac{|t-s|}{|r-s|^2} \, dr,$$
where $r, s \, \mbox{and}\, t$ are in the unit circle $\mathbb S^1=\{\zeta\in \mathbb C: \, |\zeta|=1\}$. More precisely, I want to prove that, there exist a constant $C$ independent of $s, t \in \mathbb S^1$ such that 
$$I_{s,t}=\int_{|r-s|\geq 2|t-s|} \frac{|t-s|}{|r-s|^2} \, dr< C.$$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you mean "I would like to estimate the integral..."?

Comment: Also, when you say $r,s,t$ are in the unit circle, do you mean $|s|<1, \; |t|<1,$ and $|r|<1?$ Or do you mean $|s|=1, \; |t|=1, \; |r|=1?$

Comment: @ Adrian Keister: yes that what I would like to say and  $\zeta\in \mathbb S^1$ i.e., $|\zeta|=1$. Thanks

Comment: Great! This is an interesting problem, +1. I'm going to think about it some.

Comment: Do you know if $t$ can equal $s?$

Comment: If $t=s$ $I_{s,t}=0$ and the esitmate is checked (true) for $C>0$ .

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible. The problem is, if $t\not=s,$ then the integrand is bounded in size, but it's bounded by something that is dependent on $t$ and $s$, which is itself not bounded. Let $D=\{r\in\mathbb{S}^2:|r-s|\ge 2|t-s| \}.$ From the domain $D$ over which we are integrating, we have that 
\begin{align*}
|r-s|&\ge 2|t-s| \\
\frac{1}{|r-s|}&\le\frac{1}{2|t-s|} \\
\frac{1}{|r-s|^2}&\le\frac{1}{4|t-s|^2} \\
\frac{|t-s|}{|r-s|^2}&\le\frac{1}{4|t-s|}.
\end{align*}
The $ML$ estimate would then say that
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_D\frac{|t-s|}{|r-s|^2}\,dr\right|&\le \left|\int_D\frac{1}{4|t-s|}\,dr\right| \\
&=\frac{1}{4|t-s|}\left|\int_D\,dr\right| \\
&\le \frac{2\pi}{4|t-s|} \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2|t-s|}.
\end{align*}
This bound can get quite large if $t$ gets close to $s.$

I'm curious to try a few numerical calculations. Since $r,s,t\in\mathbb{S}^1,$ we can write
\begin{align*}
r&=e^{i\theta} \\
s&=e^{i\varphi} \\
t&=e^{i\xi}.
\end{align*}
Then $dr=i\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta.$ Note a curious fact: this problem is symmetric under any rotation. Moreover, we have that $|r-s|\ge 2|t-s|$ if and only if $|\theta-\varphi|\ge 2|\xi-\varphi|,$ modulo $2\pi$. This is at least true when $t\approx s,$ which is what we're concerned about. So, let us set $\varphi-\xi=0,$ (from rotational symmetry) so that the limits on the $\theta$ integral will be $\xi$ to $2\pi.$ The integral becomes
$$\int_D\frac{|t-s|}{|r-s|^2}\,dr=i\int_{\xi}^{2\pi}\frac{|e^{i\xi}-e^{i\varphi}|}{|e^{i\theta}-e^{i\varphi}|^2}\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta. $$
This we can set up in Mathematica, and the results show, indeed, that the magnitude of this integral can be quite large, depending on how close $\varphi$ is to $\xi$.

Comment: @ Adrian Keister, If $s=1$, can not hope to estimate this integral $i\int_{\xi}^{2\pi}\frac{|1-e^{i\xi}|}{|1-e^{i\theta}|^2}\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta$ independent of $\xi$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If I understand correctly, we can write

$$r=e^{iw},s=e^{iu},t=e^{iv}$$

and the integral is

$$\int_{|r-s|\ge2|t-s|}\frac{|t-s|}{(\cos w-\cos u)^2+(\sin w-\sin u)^2}e^{iw}dw
\\=|t-s|\int_{|r-s|\ge2|t-s|}\frac{e^{iw}dw}{2-2\cos w\cos u-2\sin w\sin u}
\\=|t-s|\frac{e^{iu}}2\int_{|r-s|\ge2|t-s|}\frac{e^{i(w-u)}dw}{1-\cos(w-u)}.$$

With $z:=w-u$, the indefinite integral has an analytical form

$$\int\frac{\cos z+i\sin z}{1-\cos z}dz=\frac{\sin z+2\sin^2\dfrac z2\left(z-2i\log\sin\dfrac z2\right)}{\cos z-1}.$$

Finally, the integration domain is the portion of the unit circle which is outside a circle centered at $s$, with radius $2|t-s|$. Hence, $w$ varies in a single interval delimited by the intersections of the two circles.

This allows to write the integral in a (complicated) closed-form.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust, we can take for example $s=1$ i.e, $I_{1,t}=\int_{|1-r|\geq 2|1-t|} \frac{|1-t|}{|1-r|^2} \, dr$, my question is: can not hope to estimate this integral independent of  of $t$?

Comment: @Z.Alfata: actually, there is no dependency on $t$ but just on the distance $|t-s|$, which determines the extent of the arc. There should be a way to approxmate the integrand along the arc.

Comment: $t=e^{i\theta}$ and $r=e^{ia}$ (with the condition $2a<\pi$) and we define the measure $dt$ ($=|dt|$) as the Lebesgue on $\mathbb R$,
then,
$$\int_{|1-r|\geq 2|1-t|} \frac{|1-t|}{|1-r|^2} \, dr= 2\int_{2a}^{\pi} \frac{a}{\theta^2} \, d\theta = 2a(\frac{1}{2a}-\frac{1}{\pi}) \leq 1$$ it is working now?

Comment: @Z.Alfata: I doubt it, this looks too simple.